# I have a suggestion for fixing a bug. Should I edit into question or post an answer?

Tags: discussion, bug-reports

I am curious about this.

A possible fix is, in my opinion, an answer to a question tagged with [bug](/questions/tagged/bug), even if it's from the reporter. However among the OPs of bug reports I've seen, most of them tend to include it in their questions (if they have their own idea of fixing). The finally accepted answer is usually from an SE employee, who posted it after he added [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed).

What's the guideline for such situations? What if I have a suggestion for a bug reported by others?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are reporting a bug, the answer which says what caused it/ it is fixed/why the status declined only will answer that question.

In such cases, add it in question.

That is if you are reporting a bug in layout caused by z-index, then add it to the bottom of the question

> **This can be fixed by**
>   Your solution

Or

> **The cause of this is**
>   The cause of the bug

Comment: What if the bug is reported by others?

Comment: if it is something that can be fixed by a user script, make one and add it as answer if it is not tagged with status-planned or status-review. otherwise edit the question or use comments